# Factorizations of an $n$-cycle in $S_n$ into a product $xy$ where $|x| = 2, |y| = 3$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters. When (and how) can an $n$-cycle in $S_n$ be factored into a product $xy$, where $x,y$ have orders 2,3 respectively?

More precisely, I'd like to understand the function $f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is the number of pairs $(x,y)$ (up to simultaneous conjugation) there are such that $xy$ is an $n$-cycle. I would also like to understand the possible cycle types of such $x,y$.

Comment: Similar kinds of factorization problems in the symmetric group have been studied for a long time. See for example "Some combinatorial problems associated with products of conjugacy classes of the symmetric group" by Jackson (https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(88)90062-3) or Corollary 1.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3614 for a modern statement of a typical generating function in this area. The main technique is character theory, going back to Frobenius. However, usually one restricts $x$ and $y$ to belong to a certain conjugacy class (i.e. cycle type) rather than have a certain order.

Answer (score 6):

Looks to me like it is always possible (for $n \geq 3$).

If $n = 3m$, then take $\sigma =(123)(456) \cdots (3m-2\ 3m-2 \ 3m)$, $\tau = (34)(67) \cdots (3m-3\ 3m-2)$ and $\tau \sigma$ is an $n$-cycle.

If $n=3m+1$, use the same idea with $\sigma =(123)(456) \cdots (3m-2\ 3m-2 \ 3m)$, $\tau = (34)(67) \cdots (3m-3\ 3m-2) (3m\ 3m+1)$.

And, if $n=3m+2$, use $\sigma =(123)(456) \cdots (3m-2\ 3m-2 \ 3m)$, $\tau = (0 1)(34)(67) \cdots (3m-3\ 3m-2) (3m\ 3m+1)$

Answer (score 3):

Always (assuming $x$ and $y$ are allowed to have order $1$ in small $n$ cases).

For an example take a tree with $n/2$ edges, with half-edges allowed, where each vertex has degree either $3$ or $1$, embed it in the plane, let $x$ send an oriented edge to the same edge with the opposite orientation and let $y$ send an edge pointing at the vertex to the clockwise-next edge pointing to that vertex. Half-edges have only one vertex and both orientations count as the same.